# jMeter ignoring Thread groups

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-maven-plugin

I am using jMeter to do some performance testing. 
All thread groups are almost identical - differs only in name and in http request inside (see structure below). Although all are defined the same, the run seems to ignore some of those. Only two out of 10 are running.
I have set the log level to debug and there is still no mention of the other TG (thread groups). It's not even first two that would work, but more like third and fifth or so.
Doesn't make any sense to me. Any ideas?

I have following definition:

```
Test Plan
- variables#1 - constants
- variables#2 - environment variables (user defined)
- variables#3 - another variables used to enable/disable certain tests
- CSV dataset config - data#1
- CSV dataset config - data#2
- HTTP Request defaults (hostname, protocol and port are defined) + implicit parameters (e.g. callingApp=jmeter - part of GET in url)
-view results tree
-log aggregate report
-thread group A (arrivals - extension)
--If Controller*1
---HTTP request with specific path
----some assertions
-thread group B - E (all are the same as A, only different urls are used)
```

Ran using:

```
$config="-DrampUpTime=1 ..."
mvn clean verify $config
```

Didn't find anything in related logs or any of the settings

Related pom.xml bits:

```
plugin:com.lazerycode.jmeter:jmeter-maven-plugin:2.9.0
plugin-<config>
<jmeterVersion>5.1.1</jmeterVersion>
<overrideRootLogLevel>DEBUG</overrideRootLogLevel>
<resultsFileFormat>jtl</resultsFileFormat>
<jmeterExtensions>
<artifact>kg.apc:jmeter-plugins-casutg:${jmeter.plugins.catsug.version}</artifact>
</jmeterExtensions>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shoot me now. Just found it.

```
<com.blazemeter.jmeter.threads.arrivals.ArrivalsThreadGroup guiclass="com.blazemeter.jmeter.threads.arrivals.ArrivalsThreadGroupGui" testclass="com.blazemeter.jmeter.threads.arrivals.ArrivalsThreadGroup" testname="/something/something/something" enabled="false">
```

**enabled="false"**

Apparently there is a possibility to disable the test and for fun it only differs in slightly more gray font (in the dark theme) in GUI.
On my defense, I did not create the test suite, so at least it was not me, who disabled it.

wastedHoursCounter=5;